# Message of "Woops! Something went wrong. Please try again." when creating new users in Strapi

Tags: authentication, permissions, strapi, user-permissions

I am trying to create a new user for a Strapi aplication. I was sending a POST request form Postman and I was getting an error. So, after seeing this, I tried doing it from the Strapi interface at `http://localhost:1337/admin/`, but even this way I get an error.

[image: Error after clicking "create new entry" in Users collection-type]

I thought it could be something related to permissions, but I think everything is right.

[image: Role permissions]

I tried to find something in the Internet, starting a new aplication... but nothing works. Is someone facing the same issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I recently faced a similar error. steps to fix

1. First open up your network tab then refresh the page.
2. Is the data request 200 ? means that the data is comming fine but the error originates while rendering it. if not means there is some db mismatch issue. delete your build folder and re run the app it should fix this.
3. If its the first case then generally the issue is that you are using a component which is not getting named. for example suppose you have a repeatable component which only has a relation inside it. so when you try to create an entry ( without any string attribute ) it will try to take the relation object as name and that throws an error. so creating a name attribute inside the component will simply fix this.
4. look for such a loophole, you can also check the console, if it says object undefined or any error related to object its generally the above reason.

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Read documentation:

✔︎ Prerequisites

Before installing Strapi, the following requirements must be installed on your computer:

```
Node.js: Only Maintenance and LTS versions are supported (v14, v16, and v18).
    Node v18.x is recommended for Strapi v4.3.9 and above
    Node v16.x is recommended for Strapi v4.0.x to v4.3.8.
Your preferred Node.js package manager:
    npm (v6 only)
    yarn
Python (if using a SQLite database)
```

https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/quick-start#_1-install-strapi-and-create-a-new-project

Comment: That's not the problem... I tried with different versions and always the same problem

Comment: Version is not the problem. I am trying to resolve it currently on my project.